# Декартово произведение нескольких массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, множества, умножение

Как можно реализовать [декартово произведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) нескольких массивов в JavaScript?

```
// например
cartesian([1,2], [10,20], [100,200,300])
// будет равно
// [[1, 10, 100], [1, 10, 200], [1, 10, 300], [1, 20, 100], [1, 20, 200], ...]
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989/5812238

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Самый короткий способ на чистом JavaScript

```
const cartesian =
  (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [...d, e])), [[]]);
```

Данный способ корректно обрабатывает пустое декартово произведение, и также корректно работает когда в массивах есть вложенные массивы (в отличии от ответа на enSO!).

Используются:

- методы для массивов [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [оператор расширения `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) и
- [синтаксис оставшихся аргументов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters)

## То же самое с комментариями

```
const cartesian = (...arrays) =>
    // итеративно получаем декартово произведение
    // нескольких первых массивов из arrays,
    // начиная с нуля массивов и пустого декартова произведения --- [[]]
    arrays.reduce((cartesianPart, array) =>
        // cartesianPart --- декартово произведение нескольких первых массивов из arrays
        cartesianPart.flatMap(cartesianPartTuple =>
            // array --- новый массив из arrays для добавления в декартово произведение
            array.map(arrayElement =>
                // cartesianPartTuple --- массив-префикс одного из элементов декартова произведения
                // arrayElement --- элемент одного из массива из arrays
                [...cartesianPartTuple, arrayElement]
            )
        ),
        [[]]
    );
```

## Нерекурсивный способ с явным построением элемента декартова произведения по его номеру

```
function cartesian(...arrays) {
    // находим число элементов в декартовом произведении
    let resultLength = 1;
    for (const array of arrays) {
        resultLength *= array.length;
    }

    // создаём массив такого размера и перебираем номер элемента
    const result = new Array(resultLength);
    for (let i = 0; i < resultLength; ++i) {
        // один элемент декартова произведения
        const tuple = new Array(arrays.length);
        let tupleIndex = i;
        // цикл в обратном порядке нужен чтобы элементы начинали изменяться с конца
        for (let j = arrays.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            const array = arrays[j];
            // имеем биекцию между индексами элементов декартова произведения (числа от 0 до resultLength-1)
            // и кортежами длины arrays.length, в которых каждый элемент — индекс в соответствующем массиве
            tuple[j] = array[tupleIndex % array.length];
            // целочисленное деление
            tupleIndex = Math.floor(tupleIndex / array.length);
        }
        result[i] = tuple;
    }
    return result;
}
```

## Рекурсивный способ

С помощью рекурсии будут создаваться элементы декартова произведения: начиная с пустого массива на каждом шаге рекурсии перебираются все элементы текущего массива, создаётся копия набранного префикса элемента декартова произведения, к копии добавляется элемент массива и на полученном новом префиксе делается рекурсивный вызов.

```
function cartesian3(...arrays) {
    const result = [];
    // функция, которая будет рекурсивно вызываться
    // глубина рекурсии равна arrays.length
    // в процессе рекурсии функция будет создавать часть элемента декартова произведения
    // в конце рекусрии функция добавит созданный элемент в массив result
    const recursion = (tuplePart) => {
        if (tuplePart.length === arrays.length) {
            result.push(tuplePart);
        } else {
            const array = arrays[tuplePart.length];
            for (const element of array) {
                // создаём копию tuplePart и добавляем в неё очередной элемент
                const tuplePartWithNewElement = tuplePart.concat([element]);
                recursion(tuplePartWithNewElement);
            }
        }
    };
    recursion([]);
    return result;
}
```

## Сниппет, в котором проверяется корректность работы всех предложенных способов

```js
// cartesian 1
const cartesian1 = (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [...d, e])), [[]]);

// cartesian 1 (с комментариями)
const cartesian1b = (...arrays) =>
    // итеративно получаем декартово произведение
    // нескольких первых массивов из arrays,
    // начиная с нуля массивов и пустого декартова произведения --- [[]]
    arrays.reduce((cartesianPart, array) =>
        // cartesianPart --- декартово произведение нескольких первых массивов из arrays
        cartesianPart.flatMap(cartesianPartTuple =>
            // array --- новый массив из arrays для добавления в декартово произведение
            array.map(arrayElement =>
                // cartesianPartTuple --- массив-префикс одного из элементов декартова произведения
                // arrayElement --- элемент одного из массива из arrays
                [...cartesianPartTuple, arrayElement]
            )
        ),
        [[]]
    );

// cartesian 2
function cartesian2(...arrays) {
    // находим число элементов в декартовом произведении
    let resultLength = 1;
    for (const array of arrays) {
        resultLength *= array.length;
    }

    // создаём массив такого размера и перебираем номер элемента
    const result = new Array(resultLength);
    for (let i = 0; i < resultLength; ++i) {
        // один элемент декартова произведения
        const tuple = new Array(arrays.length);
        let tupleIndex = i;
        // цикл в обратном порядке нужен чтобы элементы начинали изменяться с конца
        for (let j = arrays.length - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            const array = arrays[j];
            // имеем биекцию между индексами элементов декартова произведения (числа от 0 до resultLength-1)
            // и кортежами длины arrays.length, в которых каждый элемент — индекс в соответствующем массиве
            tuple[j] = array[tupleIndex % array.length];
            // целочисленное деление
            tupleIndex = Math.floor(tupleIndex / array.length);
        }
        result[i] = tuple;
    }
    return result;
}

// cartesian 3
function cartesian3(...arrays) {
    const result = [];
    // функция, которая будет рекурсивно вызываться
    // глубина рекурсии равна arrays.length
    // в процессе рекурсии функция будет создавать часть элемента декартова произведения
    // в конце рекусрии функция добавит созданный элемент в массив result
    const recursion = (tuplePart) => {
        if (tuplePart.length === arrays.length) {
            result.push(tuplePart);
        } else {
            const array = arrays[tuplePart.length];
            for (const element of array) {
                // создаём копию tuplePart и добавляем в неё очередной элемент
                const tuplePartWithNewElement = tuplePart.concat([element]);
                recursion(tuplePartWithNewElement);
            }
        }
    };
    recursion([]);
    return result;
}

// tests
const cartesians = [
    cartesian1,
    cartesian1b,
    cartesian2,
    cartesian3
];

const tests = [
    {
        name: 'product of zero arrays',
        input: [],
        output: [[]]
    },
    {
        name: 'product of single array',
        input: [
            [1, 2, 3]
        ],
        output: [
            [1],
            [2],
            [3]
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'product of two arrays',
        input: [
            [1, 2, 3],
            [10, 20]
        ],
        output: [
            [1, 10],
            [1, 20],
            [2, 10],
            [2, 20],
            [3, 10],
            [3, 20]
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'product of three arrays',
        input: [
            [1, 2],
            [10, 20],
            [100, 200, 300]
        ],
        output: [
            [1, 10, 100],
            [1, 10, 200],
            [1, 10, 300],
            [1, 20, 100],
            [1, 20, 200],
            [1, 20, 300],
            [2, 10, 100],
            [2, 10, 200],
            [2, 10, 300],
            [2, 20, 100],
            [2, 20, 200],
            [2, 20, 300]
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'nested arrays',
        input: [
            [[1], [2], [3]],
            [[10], [20]]
        ],
        output: [
            [[1], [10]],
            [[1], [20]],
            [[2], [10]],
            [[2], [20]],
            [[3], [10]],
            [[3], [20]]
        ]
    }
];

console.log('если нет сообщений об ошибке, то все функции работают правильно');
cartesians.forEach((cartesian, index) => {
    for (const test of tests) {
        const output = cartesian(...test.input);
        const ok = JSON.stringify(output) === JSON.stringify(test.output);
        if (!ok) {
            console.log(`FAIL: cartesian function #${index + 1} for test ${test.name}`);
            console.log(`       expected: ${JSON.stringify(test.output)}`);
            console.log(`       received: ${JSON.stringify(output)}`);
        }
    }
});
```

## Готовые библиотечные реализации

В некоторых библиотеках существует функция декартова произведения:

- [js-combinatorics](https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics) → [`cartesianProduct`](https://github.com/dankogai/js-combinatorics#cartesian-product)
- cartesian-product — [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cartesian-product), [github](https://github.com/izaakschroeder/cartesian-product)
- [d3-array](https://github.com/d3/d3-array) → [`cross`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#cross) (только для двух массивов)

Answer (score 0):

### Прямое или декартово произведение нескольких массивов

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // несколько массивов
  let list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  let list2 = [10, 20];
  let list3 = [100, 200, 300];

  // декартово произведение трёх массивов
  let cp = cartesianProduct(list1, list2, list3);

  // вывод по столбцам
  let rows = 6;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let str = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < cp.length; j++)
      str += j % rows == i ? JSON.stringify(cp[j]) + " " : "";
    console.log(str);
  }
};

// декартово произведение нескольких массивов
function cartesianProduct(...lists) {
  // входящие данные не равны null
  if (lists == null) return null;
  // промежуточный результат
  let cp = [[]];
  // обходим входящие массивы
  for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    // текущий массив
    let list = lists[i]
    // ненулевой и непустой массив
    if (list == null || list.length == 0) continue;
    // следующий промежуточный результат
    let next = [];
    // строки текущего промежуточного результата
    for (let j = 0; j < cp.length; j++) {
      // текущая строка
      let row = cp[j];
      // элементы текущего массива
      for (let k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
        // текущий элемент
        let el = list[k];
        // новая строка для следующего
        // промежуточного результата
        let nRow = row.slice();
        nRow[row.length] = el;
        next[next.length] = nRow;
      }
    }
    // передать на следующую итерацию
    cp = next;
  }
  // итоговый результат
  return cp;
}
```